# setting up cmake to build and link pybind11

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a C++ project with a folder structure like this:

```
src/
    CMakelists.txt
    pynative/
        CMakelists.txt
        include/
        pynative.cpp        
    include/
       foo.h
       // more headers
    lib.cpp
    // more source files
```

The `pynative.cpp` file has a `PYBIND11_MODULE` definition to export some functions which use code from the parent `src/include/`. I want to compile and export the pybind11 module with all the required source code from `src/include/` and `lib.cpp`. Here's my `src/CMakelists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "CLANG")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

project(mainproj VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)
include_directories(include)
add_library(mainproj lib.cpp)
add_subdirectory(pynative)
target_link_libraries(pynative PUBLIC mainproj)
```

And here's my `pynative/CMakelists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)

project(pynative VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH C:/Users/somepath/)

find_package(pybind11 REQUIRED)
pybind11_add_module(pynative pynative.cpp)
```

This is the first time I'm working with Cmake and its hard to understand why I'm getting this error:

```
  Attempt to add link library "mainproj" to target "pynative"
  which is not built in this directory.

  This is allowed only when policy CMP0079 is set to NEW
```

The `mainproj` is just a set of functions no main so I don't want to compile it to an executable, I want it as a library which links with `pynative` to give me a Python module I can use in my code. I know `mainproj` is being built outside of `pynative` but not sure what can I do to fix this. Please help.

Also, is my current project structure a good way to organize this type of code? Should I move `mainproj` to a sibling directory?

Comment: Just set `cmake_minimum_required` to version 3.13 or later.